# Создать линейный, однонаправленный список всех чисел. Добавить последний чётный элемент в список после каждого нечётного элемента

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2015

Помогите пожалуйста, я не знаю как код дописать, а точнее добавить последний чётный элемент в список после каждого нечётного элемента

```
#include"iostream"

using namespace std;

struct SingleList {
    int data;
    SingleList* next;
};

SingleList* Make_SingleList(SingleList* head, int n) {
    head->next = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        SingleList* newItem = new SingleList;
        cout << "Enter data - " << i + 1 << "=";
        cin >> newItem->data;
        newItem->next = head;
        head = newItem;
    }
    return head;
}

void Print_SingleList(SingleList* head) {
    SingleList* current = head;
    while (current->next != 0)
    {
        cout << current->data << "  ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

SingleList* InsertItemSingleList(SingleList* head, int DataItem) {
    SingleList* Current = head;
    while (Current->next != NULL)
    {
        if (Current->data < 0) {
            SingleList* NewItem = new SingleList;
            NewItem->data = DataItem;
            NewItem->next = Current->next;
            Current->next = NewItem;
        }
        Current = Current->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void DeleteSingleList(SingleList* head) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        DeleteSingleList(head->next);
        delete head;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter n=";
    cin >> n;
    SingleList* head = new SingleList;
        head = Make_SingleList(head, n);
    cout << "make list=";
    Print_SingleList(head);
        head = InsertItemSingleList(head, "последнее чётное число");
    cout << "list with inserts=";
    Print_SingleList(head);
    cout << "Delete list" << endl;
    DeleteSingleList(head);
    Print_SingleList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое однострочный? Может массив? Или однонаправленный? И что такое парный элемент - два однаковых узла подряд? Но в любом случае алгоритм простой - 1. находите последний парный элемент. 2. проходите по списку сначала и делаете вставку ранее найденного после каждого непарного.

Comment: список всех чисел  есть бесконечная последовательность.... Переформулируйте так, чтобы было ясно что нужно и где затруднения.

Comment: однонаправленный*, можешь ли ты дописать код, пожалуйста, а-то я не до конца понимаю(

Comment: Изменил условие, попробуйте заново просмотреть и понять